# UIImage to CCSprite cocos2d v 2.0

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, cctexturecache

Moved to version 2.0 of `Cocos2D` but I'm trying to find a workaround solution to convert `UIImage` to `CCSprite`, previous one like:

```
        CCTexture2D *texture = [[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:tempImage] autorelease];
        self.spriteImage = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
```

Note:

**tempImage is a `UIImage` object**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.spriteImage = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithCGImage:tempImage.CGImage 
                                                 key:@"unique image name"];
```

Alternatively there's also a `initWithCGImage` method in CCTexture2D if you prefer to use that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have any idea why it crashes whey I use CCSprite alternative. I got `OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[CCSprite draw] 532` ?